# How to filter a unique list if the UNIQUE formula is also searching for specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know how to do both of these things, I just can't seem to combine them.

Any way to filter my UNIQUE query if it's also using IF ISNUMBER?

Originally, I was making a helper column (T) that only returned a value if the original column (G) contained "SPAN" (looking for Spanish classes). Then I would create a unique list from that helper column and add a filter to get rid of the pesky null value, like so:

=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('reqCH'!T:T,'reqCH'!T:T<>"")))

Then I wanted to cut out the helper column, so I did an IF ISNUMBER lookup for the original column (G), like so:

=(SORT(UNIQUE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SPAN",'reqCH'!G:G)),'reqCH'!F:F))))

(I wanted it to return the value from F because that's the course ID).

But, while it's not the end of the world, I'd like to add a filter to this now so I can filter out the nulls (which returns as one FALSE value in my list). And no matter where I put the FILTER in this new formula, it fails on me.

I can change it so FALSE returns as anything else:

=(SORT(UNIQUE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SPAN",'reqCH'!G:G)),'reqCH'!F:F,"--"))))

...but I'd like to just cut it out altogether like I could with FILTER.

Comment: Do  you mean: `=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('reqCH'!F:F,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SPAN",'reqCH'!G:G)))))`

Comment: Thanks, @Rory. I want to mark it solved, but I think this was put in as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I think you mean this:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('reqCH'!F:F,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SPAN",'reqCH'!G:G)))))
```